# Policy pod start at eviction

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod, evict

I have a problem: I use eviction policies (evict-soft and evict-hard) and when my pods are being evicted out beacause of resource lack on one node, pod dies and starts on another node, so, that during this time service is down. What can I do to make pod first start on another node before being killed on the first?

Comment: How this pod was created? Deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Run two of them and use a pod disruption budget so it won’t do a soft evict of both at the same time (or use affinity settings so they run on different nodes, or both).